# Sudden error compiling code for thr Arduino MKR WiFi 1010

Tags: c++, arduino

### The Question

Programming Arduino is something new to me - I've included what I believe is relevant, though please comment if more code/info is needed.

I'm creating a sketch that uses the `ArduinoHttpClient` library installed via the IDE's 'Manage Libraries' option.

Yesterday all was well - sketch compiles.

Today I get the error below. Nothing changed between yesterday and today that I can tell.

I have tried the code on other machines - 2 work, 1 doesn't and I cannot tell what is wrong and don't fully understand the actual error.

Can anybody explain a) what the error means and b) what i might be able to do to resolve it?

### Code pieces

> In file included from
> /Users/me/Documents/Arduino/libraries/ArduinoHttpClient/src/ArduinoHttpClient.h:8:0,
> from
> /Users/me/Documents/Proj/network-comms/ard-mkr-wifi-1010/box_register.h:1,
> from
> /Users/me/Documents/Proj/network-comms/ard-mkr-wifi-1010/ard-mkr-wifi-1010.ino:11:
> /Users/me/Documents/Arduino/libraries/ArduinoHttpClient/src/HttpClient.h:12:1:
> error: expected ',' or ';' before 'static' static const int
> HTTP_SUCCESS =0; ^~~~~~ exit status 1 Error compiling for board
> Arduino MKR WiFi 1010.

The ArduinoHttpClient.h file is as installed and unchanged:

```
// Library to simplify HTTP fetching on Arduino
// (c) Copyright Arduino. 2016
// Released under Apache License, version 2.0

#ifndef ArduinoHttpClient_h
#define ArduinoHttpClient_h

#include "HttpClient.h"
#include "WebSocketClient.h"
#include "URLEncoder.h"

#endif
```

box_register.h at line one just includes the lib

```
#include <ArduinoHttpClient.h>
```

HttpClient.h from the Arduino lib is as - includes the line being reported:

```
// Class to simplify HTTP fetching on Arduino
// (c) Copyright MCQN Ltd. 2010-2012
// Released under Apache License, version 2.0

#ifndef HttpClient_h
#define HttpClient_h

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <IPAddress.h>
#include "Client.h"

static const int HTTP_SUCCESS =0; /// <------ LINE 11 
// The end of the headers has been reached.  This consumes the '\n'
// Could not connect to the server
static const int HTTP_ERROR_CONNECTION_FAILED =-1;
// This call was made when the HttpClient class wasn't expecting it
// to be called.  Usually indicates your code is using the class
// incorrectly
static const int HTTP_ERROR_API =-2;
// Spent too long waiting for a reply
```

ard-mkr-wifi-1010.ino showing line including box_register

```
// va_start, va_end
#include <stdarg.h>

#include <WiFiNINA.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <RTCZero.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include <Wire.h>

#include "./arduino_secrets.h"
#include "./box_register.h" // <----- HERE
#include "./ntp.h"
```

Comment: You didn’t include a [mcve], but my crystal ball says your Client.h is messed up.

Comment: Honestly, I can't reproduce this on other machines so difficult to provide an example without all the source code. Interesting, I don't see a "Client.h" file in this previously working lib. do you know where it might pull that from?

Comment: oh interesting, uses the client from another lib. I'll try binning re-adding those: https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoHttpClient

Comment: Client.h is in core. <arduino15 folder>/packages/arduino/hardware/samd/1.8.11/cores/arduino/api/Client.h